# What is the difference between "garrapo" and "rungo"?

Tags: diferencias-regionales, significado, sinónimos, palabras-raras

[**Garrapo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IwXjlLF) is

> 1. m. y f. Sal. Cerdo que no ha cumplido un año.

while [**Rungo**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WqPTGa7) is

> 1. m. Sal. Cerdo de menos de un año.

From the definitions, it seems that both words are used only in Salamanca, and that they designate exactly the same. Is there any subtle difference? Are they used outside Salamanca?

Comment: I'm from Sevilla, and I've never heard such words. I'm afraid you'll have to wait for someone from Salamanca to answer this question. By the way, I've always wondered why the DRAE has definitions restricted to such local places inside Spain, but they have a separate _Diccionario de americanismos_. Maybe they should create a _Diccionario de españoladas_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el [fichero general](http://www.rae.es/recursos/banco-de-datos/fichero-general) de la RAE es en el único sitio donde he encontrado información, pero nada que explique la diferencia. De hecho, si buscas "rungo" ahí, en las definiciones concernientes a Salamanca en muchas tarjetas aparece definido directamente como "garrapo", por lo que en principio son sinónimos.

Por otro lado, buscando por Internet en general he encontrado [este texto](http://es.charla.actualidad.narkive.com/OGwvv5Tk/quien-hace-honor-a-su-nombre) que no sé qué validez tiene:

> A la cría del cerdo, en general, hasta que tiene el año, se la llama **garrapo** en casi toda la provincia, guarrapo en Las Sierras de Francia y Béjar, y en El Alto Tormes, gurriato en el oeste y suroeste de la provincia, **rungo** en El Abadengo y Tierra de Vitigudino, gurrinito en El Rebollar.

La palabra "rungo" aparece también en [esta entrada](http://cuentoquenoescuento.blogspot.com.es/2012/04/seria-conveniente-una-decidida.html) sobre "el habla popular de Lumbrales" (que sí, está en Salamanca). Y aparece definida como "garrapo"

Por tanto, parece que la única diferencia entre las palabras es que la primera parece ser de uso común en toda la provincia de Salamanca, y la otra se usa en determinadas zonas rurales.

Comment: según el DRAE, **gurriato** en  León, Zamora, Salamanca es un _cerdo pequeño_, sin aclarar si es pequeño de edad o de tamaño (no se si es un definición ambigua o equívoca)