# ¿Existen palabras en el DRAE que solo se usen en pequeñas regiones de Hispanoamérica?

Tags: rae, dle

Últimamente estamos viendo que existen palabras en el DRAE que son de uso solamente en determinadas regiones de España, como es el caso de ["garrapo" y "rungo"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18332/12637) (de uso en Salamanca) y ["costo"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18333/12637) (de uso en Cádiz). A veces he leído que al DRAE se le acusa de estar demasiado centrado en el español de España, y este tipo de definiciones parece confirmarlo. De hecho, yo pensaba que las palabras de uso demasiado local no entraban en el diccionario, aunque veo que me equivocaba.

En el caso de Hispanoamérica, sí que vemos muchas palabras en el diccionario de uso en determinados países. Sin embargo, y por comparar con el caso de España, ¿existen palabras en el DRAE que estén marcadas como de uso en pequeñas zonas o ciudades de países de Hispanoamérica, más que en el país entero?

La conclusión a la que tiendo a llegar, pero esto ya es cosa de debate y por tanto no tiene cabida en este sitio, es si no debería la RAE sacar estas palabras de uso local en España a un *diccionario de españoladas* (como me gusta llamarlo), al igual que existe un [diccionario de americanismos](http://www.asale.org/obras-y-proyectos/diccionarios/diccionario-de-americanismos).

Comment: ¡Interesante pregunta! Así como está formulada, podría caer en una tipología que [no está recomendada](/help/on-topic): _Preguntas sobre "listas", donde cada respuesta es igualmente válida_. Podría ser interesante (sugiero) centrarse en cuál es el criterio de la RAE a la hora de definir regiones y si, como parece, pone más la lupa en España que en Hispanoamérica.

Comment: @fedorqui no creo que sea una pregunta sobre listas. Es una pregunta de respuesta sí/no. Me basta con saber si existe al menos una palabra que cumpla el requisito, o si la RAE no ha contemplado esta posibilidad. La edición que sugieres podría ser una segunda pregunta en función de cómo se desarrolle esta (no adelantemos acontecimientos). :-)

Comment: De acuerdo, entiendo. En tal caso, el DIRAE puede servirnos. Es raro porque me encuentro con palabras como [_flacuchento_](http://dirae.es/palabras/flacuchento) que en el DIRAE consta _1. adj. Á. Andes, Chile..._ pero luego el DRAE menciona como _1. adj. Arg., Bol., Chile_. Es decir, el DRAE estandariza la región (Andes argentinos) a todo el país (Argentina).

Comment: @fedorqui claro, el problema con el DIRAE es que las definiciones que tiene almacenadas son la de la versión anterior del diccionario (2001). En esa edición la palabra que mencionas viene recogida como de uso en el "área de los Andes", además de en otras regiones (países). A eso se le añade el que a priori desconozco los nombres de las regiones en las que se dividen otros países que no sean España, y no sé por tanto cómo buscarlas en el DIRAE. Esperaba que alguien se hubiera topado ya con alguna palabra que cumpliera estos requisitos.

Comment: Entonces parece que el último diccionario (el posterior al de 2001) ha modificado la forma de mencionar regiones y solo habla de países (otro ejemplo, con [sapallo](http://dirae.es/palabras/sapallo)). Yo he estado buscando en el DIRAE nombres de ciudades y regiones que conozco de por allí, pero no sale nada. En cambio, buscando [_Salamanca_](http://dirae.es/palabras/?q=salamanca) he encontado un montón.

Comment: @fedorqui efectivamente, ahí es donde quiero llegar. Incluso si te fijas, en la versión de 2001 las áreas tampoco es que fueran pequeñas: el área de los Andes no es moco de pavo, y la "América meridional" tampoco. Si la pregunta queda finalmente sin respuesta, consideraré que la respuesta es simplemente "no".

Comment: Nótese que [el diccionario de 2001 - 22ª edición](http://www.rae.es/recursos/diccionarios/diccionarios-anteriores-1726-2001/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola-2001) se presentó hablando de _la incorporación de un gran número de voces y acepciones del español de América_. No veo comentarios sobre cambios de política en la [23ª edición - versión de 2014](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola/la-23a-edicion-2014), pero claramente algo hay.

Comment: ¡Mira! En [La vigesimotercera edición del Diccionario de la Real Academia Española](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/La_vigesimotercera_edicion.pdf) - ojo, es un pdf -, dice _En cuanto a la MARCACIÓN GEOGRÁFICA, a partir de esta edición se utiliza la marca «Am.» (América) para
aquellas acepciones con uso atestiguado en catorce países americanos o más. (...) Además, se ha procurado incorporar en un
mayor número de ocasiones la marca correspondiente a España («Esp.»)_. Estamos cerca.

Comment: @fedorqui efectivamente, creo que estamos cerca de que puedas redactar un "no" por respuesta, me temo. :-)

Comment: Encontré algunos casos límite: ¿Se valen subconjuntos de más de un país? Por ejemplo: rural en Argentina, Ecuador y Perú? Entonces está [achalay](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0PmIraZ), ¿y las Antillas? Canarias supongo que las consideras parte de España. Al parecer, en versiones antiguas era común: Encontré varias como [acatanca](http://dirae.es/palabras/acatanca) que en el '83 decía *NO de Arg.*, pero en la versión actual dice sólo *Arg.*. También [abreviar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0Ao5126), Costa Rica, rural (aunque también se usa con esa acepción en otros países). [Fuente](http://dirae.es/marcas)

Comment: @Rafael la fuente que indico en mi respuesta creo que cierra la duda: por decisión de quien lo redactó, el DRAE actual de 2014 no hace menciones a regiones más pequeñas que un país, incluyendo una entrada solo en el caso de que sea usada en al menos tres. Luego podemos debatir cuál es el ámbito de la pregunta, si una palabra se incluyó relacionándola con un país entero a pesar de que pertenezca a una sola región, etc. Pero creo que eso ya es otro tema.

Comment: @fedorqui pero lo que citas bien se puede entender como criterio para la inclusión de términos _nuevos_, y el hecho es que todavía _quedan_ entradas en el diccionario que no lo cumplen, como hemos visto varios ejemplos.

Comment: @Rafael caramba, tienes razón. Claramente leí mal la propia referencia que yo puse, pues la interpreté como el criterio para todas las entradas del diccionario. Llevas razón en que se refiere solamente a las nuevas. Gracias por la puntualización.

Comment: @Rafael ciertamente, tus casos están al límite. Entiendo que la palabra "achalay" más que de una zona concreta sería de ámbito rural pero en todo el país (o países). Aun así cumpliría con que sería una palabra no usada en todo el país y por tanto habrían hilado más fino. Con todo, creo que sigue sin ser exactamente lo que buscaba, pero reconozco que tus aportes son muy buenos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A la pregunta

> ¿existen palabras en el DRAE que estén marcadas como de uso en pequeñas zonas o ciudades de países de Hispanoamérica, más que en el país entero?

Si nos referimos a palabras de nueva inclusión, la respuesta es:

## No

En 2014 al presentar la [23ª edición del diccionario](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-de-la-lengua-espanola/la-23a-edicion-2014), la vigente, el periódico uruguayo El País entrevistó a Pedro Álvarez de Miranda, director de la obra y bajo el título de [Los americanismos crecen en el nuevo diccionario de la Lengua Española](http://www.elpais.com.uy/vida-actual/americanismos-crecen-nuevo-diccionario-rae.html) podemos leer:

> La nueva edición del Diccionario, trece años después de su última salida en 2001, se ha armonizado con el Diccionario de Americanismos, de manera que **se "ha acordado la inclusión de los americanismos que se usen al menos en tres países**", añadió Álvarez de Miranda.

Por lo que no, por decisión editorial el DRAE de 2014 no debería contener entradas nuevas que se refieran a una región más pequeña que un país.

Otra cosa es que antes de esa fecha ya hubiera alguna, como apunta Rafael en su respuesta.

En el pdf enlazado en la página de la RAE [La vigesimotercera edición](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/La_vigesimotercera_edicion.pdf) se menciona:

> En cuanto a la MARCACIÓN GEOGRÁFICA, a partir de esta edición se utiliza la marca «Am.» (América) para aquellas acepciones con uso atestiguado en catorce países americanos o más. (...) Además, se ha procurado incorporar en un mayor número de ocasiones la marca correspondiente a España («Esp.»).

Por tanto, parece que la tendencia es de asociar cada palabra a países, en lugar de regiones. Será interesante ver si esto también implica eliminar entradas muy específicas de zonas concretas de España, así como editar las existentes de zonas de Hispanoamérica para asociarlas a un país en lugar de una región.

De hecho, al hilo de un festival cultural mexicano de septiembre de 2016, la BBC escribió un artículo [Las primeras palabras latinoamericanas que entraron al diccionario de la Real Academia Española (RAE)](http://www.bbc.com/mundo/noticias-36847933) en el que aborda esta descompensación, además de realizar un interesante repaso histórico de la evolución de las academias de la lengua:

> Una crítica muy frecuente que se le ha hecho al diccionario de la RAE es ser hispanocentrista.
>
> Con la aparición de las primeras academias americanas — la primera fue la Academia Colombiana de la Lengua, fundada en 1871 — la cuota de "americanismos" incluidos en las nuevas versiones del diccionario aumentó de forma considerable.
>
> Y más aún con la Asociación de Academias de la Lengua Española (ASALE), conformada en México en 1951 e integrada por las 23 academias de la lengua española existentes en el mundo.
>
> "Ahora mismo se está decidiendo cómo será el nuevo diccionario, pero se tiene claro que deberá funcionar en pie de igualdad", asegura.
>
> "Que no sea la Real Academia Española la que decida qué voces se aceptan y cuáles no, sino que lo hagan todas por igual".

---

Como curiosidad, en la noticia de El País Álvarez de Miranda indica que:

> "Hemos sido más rápidos de lo habitual aceptando 'tuit' y 'tuitero'", dijo el director de la RAE, José Manuel Blecua.
> El diccionario "intenta reflejar como un modelo lo que es la situación de la lengua en estos momentos", explicó Blecua.

Comment: La pregunta no implicaba el que existieran palabras que sólo se usasen en determinadas regiones de países aparte de España, sino que además estuvieran marcadas en el diccionario con el nombre de dicha región. Veo que a lo más aparecen (o aparecían) especificaciones como "noroeste", o "rural", lo cual no me sirve como respuesta, ya que buscaba nombres concretos, como "Salamanca" o "Cádiz" en el caso de los ejemplos propuestos para España. Doy pues esta respuesta como aceptada.

Answer (score 4):

Tal como se menciona en los comentarios, pareciera que la RAE intencionalmente atribuye al país americanismos que pueden ser más locales. A la espera de que aparezca un contraejemplo (quizá haya alguno en México, por ser un país extenso y no *demasiado* centralizado), creo que de todas formas no se puede excluir sin más los localismos de países que constituyen un porcentaje muy bajo del mundo hispanohablante. Respondería que hasta cierto punto:

**Sí**

El DLE al menos acepta localismos de fuera de España y que son usados por un porcentaje que se podría considerar marginal de hablantes.

Por ejemplo, Chile está lleno de chilenismos, y algunos de ellos han llegado al diccionario sin pasar por otros países. Si se toma por población (más desfavorable que por área), Chile es *chico* en relación al mundo hispanohablante: 18 millones, que corresponden a un 3 o 4% del total (según si se consideran o no los que lo hablan como segundo idioma, equivalente a dos o tres comunidades autónomas grandes en España, o un tercio de su población total).

El primer chilenismo que se me viene a la cabeza es [*condoro*](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ACKPj8r), y al menos el DLE me da la razón:

> **condoro**: 1. m. *Chile*. Torpeza grave y vergonzosa.

Otros ejemplos incluyen acepciones particulares de palabras con otros significados como *[huaso](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Jlk2fOS)*, *[patudo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SC8ktVo)* y vulgaridades como *[huevada](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KlpCsWJ)*.

Comment: Mmmm interesante manera de verlo. Supongo que Carlos se refería a regines más pequeñas que un país, independientemente del número de habitantes. Pero si tiramos de este hilo, una palabra de Uruguay (4 millones de habitantes) Paraguay (7) o Bolivia (10) sería incluso más _rara_.

Comment: La pregunta específica "palabras marcadas como de uso en pequeñas zonas o ciudades de países de Hispanoamérica, **más que en el país entero**", por lo que los chilenismos no son ejemplos válidos.

Comment: @user13560 tienes razón, me quedé con el argumento de que la respuesta era **no** por lo de *al menos tres países*. De hecho, como se dice en los comentarios el DLE tiende a generalizar al país americanismos que a veces son más locales. Voy a editar un poco la respuesta para aclarar el punto, pero me parece que de todos modos sirve de antecedente.

Comment: Ciertamente, la pregunta iba más dirigida a saber si la unidad territorial mínima en Hispanoamérica para la RAE era simplemente el país, o si desgrana un poco más hasta el nivel de provincia como en España. Todo con independencia del número de habitantes del país. En todo caso, te agradezco tu respuesta, es interesante ver que, al menos, ya desgranan hasta el nivel de país en Hispanoamérica, van mejorando.

Answer (score 1):

En la versión de 1983 del DRAE era común encontrar [marcas lexicográficas](http://dirae.es/marcas) para atribuir voces a regiones dentro de países latinoamericanos, individualizadas no por nombre, sino por *puntos cardinales* (p.ej., **Noroeste de Argentina**, **Este de Bolivia**, etc.). La mayoría de esas voces (probablemente todas) en la versión actual han perdido esa especificación y son atribuidas al país completo. Dos ejemplos:

- *Acatanca* [en 1983](http://dirae.es/palabras/acatanca) decía *Noroeste* de Arg., [hoy](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0JjZ9Wx) sólo Arg.
- *Toco* [en 1983](http://dirae.es/palabras/toco) decía *Este* de Bol., [hoy](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZwvgxDI) sólo Bol.

La única marca lexicográfica (que he podido encontrar hasta ahora) que modifica al país, especifícandolo, es **rural**. No se trata de una región en sentido estricto, eso sí. Ejemplo:

- *Acodillado* dice *rur. Arg.* tanto [en 1983](http://dirae.es/palabras/acodillado) como en la [versión actual](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0Vv44cN).