# ¿Qué es un "mandado" en Cuba?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, cuba

Estaba leyendo un artículo probablemente escrito en México en el que mencionaban algo así como *es muy difícil hacer mandados cuando tienes un bebé*.

No me sonaba la palabra, así que la busqué en el DRAE:

> [**mandado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O9JMnp7)
>   Del part. de mandar.
>   1. m. y f. Persona que ejecuta una comisión por encargo ajeno.
>   2. m. Orden, precepto, mandamiento.
>   3. m. Comisión que se da en paraje distinto de aquel en que ha de ser desempeñada.
>   4. m. Cuba, Méx. y Nic. Compra de lo necesario para la comida.
>   5. m. Cuba. pene.
>   6. m. desus. Aviso o noticia.
>   petiso de los mandados

Vale, queda claro que se trata de hacer la compra (*make groceries* dirían en inglés, creo).

Pero claro, luego leyendo toda las acepciones me sorprendió que dos acepciones coexistan. Las remarco repitiéndolas:

> [**mandado, da**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=O9JMnp7)
>   4. m. Cuba, Méx. y Nic. Compra de lo necesario para la comida.
>   5. m. Cuba. pene.

Es decir, en Cuba un *mandado* puede referirse tanto a hacer la compra como al pene. ¿Cómo puede ser eso? ¿Se usa en el mismo contexto? ¿Podría darse el caso que se utilice cada palabra [en distintas partes de Cuba](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18343/1674)?

Comment: Ya te puedo confirmar que aquí en Andalucía (al menos en la zona de Sevilla y Cádiz) todo el mundo te va a entender si les dices que tienes un buen _mandao_. :-) De hecho, también he ido con frecuencia a hacer mandados (recados). No se usan en el mismo contexto, por supuesto.

Comment: También se usa como sinónimo de golpe en _dar un mandao a alguien_ (nunca lo he oído como _manda**d**o_). No sabría decir en qué regiones se usa exactamente, pero creo que está bastante extendido en España.

Comment: Usamos la misma locucion en Argentina para significar 'hacer las compras'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El significado de mandado en Cuba es un poco más amplio. "Hacer un mandado" o "Ir a un mandado" es ir a hacer una gestión (Ir de compras es un ejemplo). Esta gestión puede ser algo que alguien te mandó a hacer. Por ejemplo una madre que manda al hijo a comprar o buscar algo. Por eso al preguntar por alguien puede que te respondan: fue a un mandado.

Los mandados son los productos racionados y subvencionados que se venden a toda la población normalmente una vez al mes.
"Fui a comprar los mandados"
"Ya llegaron los mandados"

Comment: El primer párrafo vale para México también.  Otro ejemplo: si te mandan a pagar el recibo de luz, eso también es un mandado.

Answer (score 5):

En Cuba se usa "hacer los mandados" como "hacer las compras" (normalmente de comida, productos agrícolas, etc.

La acepción de pene se usa coloquialmente aunque no muy frecuentemente: *Me saqué mi mandado al aire. Le enseñé mi paquete*, etc. Sin embargo no es la primera palabra que yo asociaría con pene (sin contexto alguno).

Fuente: yo, nacido y crecido en aquel país. ;)

Comment: ¿Y qué hay de la acepción que indica que también quiere decir _pene_? ¿Se usa también con la misma frecuencia y/o regiones?

Comment: La acepción de pene se usa coloquialmente aunque no muy frecuentemente. Me saqué mi mandado al aire. Le enseñé mi paquete, etc. Sin embargo no es la primera palabra que yo asociaría con pene (sin contexto alguno).

Comment: ¡Gracias! ¿Podrías echarle una ojeada a esta otra pregunta en la que consultan sobre el uso de _bote_ en Cuba? [¿Se utilizan estas acepciones regionales de “bote”?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18432/1674)