# ¿Se utilizan estas acepciones regionales de "bote"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, definiciones, diferencias-regionales

He encontrado en el DRAE unas acepciones de [**bote**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5yatllK%7C5yboas9%7C5yc2i2E%7C5ycMwec%7C5ycy6L2%7C5yg7rxF) que desconocía:

> (1) (*de botar*)
>   5. m. Pan. **aventón** (‖ autoestop).
>
> (3) (*Del ingl. ant. bāt.*)
>   2. m. coloq. Guat., Hond. y Méx. **prisión** (‖ cárcel).
>
> (4) (*Del germ. *bukko; cf. a. al. medio boc, a. al. ant. bukk, al. Bock.*)
>   1. m. rur. coloq. Sor. **cabrón** (‖ macho de la cabra).
>
> (6) 1. m. Cuba. **Hoja pequeña de tabaco, después del primer corte, usada para la picadura.**

¿Se utilizan en la vida normal (en las regiones correspondientes) o son acepciones que entraron en el diccionario en el pasado pero actualmente desusadas?

Answer (score 1):

Creo interesante comparar las entradas en el DRAE con las que hay en el [Diccionario de americanismos para la palabra *bote*](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=2tZJTZDZ9x0ASpwr0g1).

Ahí leemos:

> [**bote**](http://lema.rae.es/damer/srv/search?id=2tZJTZDZ9x0ASpwr0g1)
>
> I.    1.  m. Mx, Gu, Ho, Ni, CR, Bo, Ch; Cu, delinc; Ec, juv. Cárcel. pop + cult → espon. ◆ chirola; cholpa.
>   2.  Cu. Vehículo de la policía.
>   3.  Bo. Celda en un retén policial. delinc.
>
> II.   1.  m. Mx. Nalga de una persona. pop + cult → espon.
>
> III.  1.  m. Ur; Ar, p.u. Automóvil grande y lujoso. pop + cult → espon ^ fest.
>   2.  Ur. Ómnibus. pop + cult → espon.
>
> IV.   1.  m. Co. Vuelta ligera dada por alguien en el aire.
>
> V.    1.  m. Ur; Ar, p.u. Zapato muy grande. pop + cult → espon ^ fest.
>
> VI.   1.  m. Ve. Salida de gas o líquido por un orificio o abertura producido accidentalmente.
>
> VII.  1.  m. CR. Acción de pasar a la palma de la mano un trompo que está bailando y arrojarlo nuevamente al sitio donde se tomó para que continúe rotando.
>
> VIII. (De botar).
>   1.  Pa. aventón, autoestop.

También hay entradas compuestas del tipo *bote de basura*, pero no las copio porque no parecen relevantes para el caso que nos incumbe.

### Por tanto, de las que comentas veo que dos sí están descritas

> (1) (*de botar*)
>   5. m. Pan. **aventón** (‖ autoestop).

Coincide con:

> VIII. (De botar).
>   1.  Pa. aventón, autoestop.

---

> (3) (*Del ingl. ant. bāt.*)
>   2. m. coloq. Guat., Hond. y Méx. **prisión** (‖ cárcel).

Coincide con:

> I.    1.  m. Mx, Gu, Ho, Ni, CR, Bo, Ch; Cu, delinc; Ec, juv. Cárcel. pop + cult → espon. ◆ chirola; cholpa.

---

### La siguiente no tiene referencias

> (6) 1. m. Cuba. **Hoja pequeña de tabaco, después del primer corte, usada para la picadura.**

Buscando en Google no encuentro entradas relevantes más allá de alguna que menciona esta entrada del diccionario. Lo [consulté](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/18377/1674) a un usuario cubano, ojalá pueda contestar en algún momento.

El *Mapa de diccionarios* la introdujo en 2001.

---

### Y otra se usa en Soria

> (4) (*Del germ. *bukko; cf. a. al. medio boc, a. al. ant. bukk, al. Bock.*)
>   1. m. rur. coloq. Sor. **cabrón** (‖ macho de la cabra).

Aquí, *rur. coloq. Sor.* quiere decir *rural coloquial Soria*, donde esta es una provincia española cercana a Madrid.

Otra vez el *Mapa de diccionarios* sale en nuestra ayuda para indicarnos que sus definiciones previas eran:

- 2001: *1. f. coloq. rur. Sor. macho cabrío.*
- 1992: *f. Sor. macho cabrío.*
- 1925: *6. Boche, 1.er art.*
- 1884: *Boche, 1.er art.*

Mirando [boche](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5jHlfag%7C5jIrN38%7C5jK6PFt%7C5jKPcB6) vemos que se nos redirige actualmente a buche:

> [**buche<sup>2</sup>, cha**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6DBWrje)
>   De la voz buch, con que se llama a este animal.
>   1. m. y f. Asno recién nacido y mientras mama.

Y el uso de *asno*, *cabrón*, siempre ha tenido adeptos en el uso como insulto. Desconozco si se usa aún. Teniendo en cuenta lo pequeña que es Soria (menos de cien mil habitantes, según la [Wiki](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Provincia_de_Soria)) y que parece de un ámbito muy rural, dudo que se use demasiado y probablemente la RAE lo mantiene como algo histórico. Es el tipo de palabras que si no estuviera ya en el diccionario, dudo que se la aceptara hoy en día.

Comment: Es curiosa esa etimología boche <- buche <- buch ! Yo solo conocía la acepción de boche = (despectivo) alemán, con origen en el alemán Bock (como en "bote" en Soria)

Comment: @Luigi ya te digo. Lo curioso es que un término alemán solo penetrara en la Soria rural...

Comment: Me parece que la pregunta va dirigida a si se utilizan en la vida real hoy día esas acepciones, no si están recogidas en otros diccionarios