# ¿Por qué en España se denomina "pistola" a la barra de pan?

Tags: vocabulario, etimología, españa

La tercera acepción de [**pistola**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TDlEzRN) en el Dicccionario de la Lengua es:

> 3. f. *Esp.* Barra de pan de unos 250 g.

¿De dónde viene este uso?

Answer (score 7):

No en todas partes de España se le dice `pistola`, ni se le dice `pistola` a cualquier tipo de pan. El término "pistola" es [típico de Madrid](http://maspan.blogspot.com/2007/07/barra-pistola-el-pan-de-madrid.html). Hay muchos tipos de pan. La pistola es una barra larga y crujiente, más gruesa que la *baguette*. El mismo tipo de barra de pan recibirá otro nombre en otros sitios, o se le llamará simplemente "barra de pan".

[Esta web](http://www.sabormadrid.es/novedades/curiosidades/procedencia-del-nombre-pistola-barra-de-pan.php) aporta a un par de teorías:

> Existen diversas teorías, una de ellas dice que los alemanes son los artífices del nombre, ya que por su forma llaman al pan flauta, que en alemán se dice ‘pistole’. La palabra francesa “pistolet” también es un tipo de pan belga.
>
> [otra teoría es que] el término pistola para referirse a la barra de pan desde los años 60, [viene] derivado del italiano, ya que panadero en latín se conoce como ‘pistor’ y la terminación -ula (-ola) se refiere a la barrita de pan.

También hay una referencia a un chiste que dice que recibe ese nombre porque sirve "para matar el hambre".

Comment: Es curioso, no sabía  que en Madrid se le llamaba pistola a la barra de pan, aquí en Euskadi la pistola o _sopako_ es un pan duro, casi quemado, para hacer sopa de ajo y otras recetas del estilo, muchas veces tiene forma de rosca ovalada

Comment: Buen apunte el de la localización. A mí me suena la palabra por que mi padre era de Madrid, no sé si se usa en otras partes de España, pero aquí en Canarias si vas a una panadería y pides una pistola... o se parten de risa o llaman a la policía.

Comment: Un enlace a [tipos de panes](http://www.creativegan.net/archives/tipos-de-panes/).

Comment: La definición del diccionario indica  _**Esp**_, no _**Mad**_ (aunque pueden estar equivocados, claro), y si  especifica que es un tipo concreto de pan: "**_barra de unos 250 g_**" y no cualquiera.

Comment: @Nox lo mismo digo, no conozco ningún sitio en Andalucía en el que llamen "pistola" a algún tipo de pan.

Comment: @user probablemente tenga que ver con lo descrito en [¿Existen palabras en el DRAE que solo se usen en pequeñas regiones de Hispanoamérica?](http://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18343/1674): en este caso podría ser que la palabra fuera de una región concreta pero el DRAE solo refleja el país entero.

Comment: La teoría italiana no es creíble. En italiano no quedan rasgos de pistor. Pistola es una arma de fuego y en algunos lugares del norte un insulto blando (como salame)

Answer (score 2):

Oí una vez que en Madrid se llamaba pistola a ese tipo de pan porque, durante la ocupación francesa, se prohibió hacer en Madrid panes grandes y hogazas porque se habían dado casos de suministrar armas a los presos metidas en ellos. La forma de la pistola impedía introducir pistolas de verdad en ellas. Sólo quedó el recurso al recochineo, tan propio de los madriles. Pero pude oír una historia inventada, claro.