# En el DLE ¿hay más casos de acepciones tan localizadas regionalmente como la 5ª de "cuesco"?

Tags: definiciones, dle

La quinta acepción de [**cuesco**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BatAWF0) en el DLE es:

> 5. m. *Ingen*. En las minas de Riotinto, España, escoria procedente de los hornos de manga.

Me ha llamado la atención el que hace referencia a una localización geográfica muy limitada y concreta: "*En las **minas de Riotinto, España***".

Las otras voces del DLE que recuerdo con una referencia geográfica concreta son todas a provincias o  regiones (por ejemplo: *Soria* en [**bote**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5ycMwec)). Pero ¿una mina?

¿Hay otros casos similares, de localización extrema?

Comment: ¿No se tratará del municipio? [Minas de Riotinto](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minas_de_Riotinto)

Comment: @MauricioMartinez: no creo, porque en el DLE viene "**minas**" con minúscula, no **Minas**. Pero aunque lo fuera, ¿una acepción para el uso en un solo municipio de 4.000 habitantes? También sería una localización geográfica extrema

Comment: Si, tienes razón, parece la mina como tal. Bastante curioso.

Comment: Una [pregunta preexistente](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18332/5481) menciona "garrapo" y "rungo", ambas usadas en _Salamanca_.  [Otra](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/18333/5481) menciona "costo", usado en _Cádiz_. Puede que tengas otro ejemplo con ["puerto"](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UahFsZE), en su 9a acepción, que se refiere a su uso no en una región sino por una asociación. Este es un caso parecido, si consideramos ambas palabras como "argot" dentro de un gremio o distinto si l oque buscamos es localización geográfica.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Acá van algunas.

Las minas (y hornos) de Almadén parecen ser bastante populares en el DRAE. Sospecho de algún académico almadenense.

> [**asnado**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=41XV8pm)
> **1.** m. En las minas de Almadén, en España, cada madero de los que se ponen de trecho en trecho para asegurar los costados de la mina.
>
> [**cochura**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9ag32aV)
> **3.** f. *Ingen.* En los hornos de Almadén, en España, calcinación de una carga de mineral de azogue.
>
> [**garduja**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ItNuTlR)
> **1.** f. En las minas de Almadén, piedra que, por no tener ley de azogue, se arroja como inútil.
>
> [**hacendero, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=JwcK77M)
> **2.** m. En las minas de Almadén, en España, operario que trabajaba a jornal por cuenta del Estado.
>
> [**hurto**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KqswHG3)
> **3.** m. En las minas de Almadén, en España, camino subterráneo a uno y otro lado del principal, para facilitar la extracción de metales o dar comunicación al aire, o para otros fines.
>
> [**roncador**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WfsHdY3)
> **3.** m. En las minas de Almadén, España, encargado de gobernar y vigilar a cierto número de obreros.

...y no sigo con Almadén.

La universidad de Alcalá tiene también sus entradas:

> [**deán**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BtSFzGY)
> **2.** m. En la antigua universidad española de Alcalá, graduado más antiguo de cada facultad.
>
> [**licencia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NG6NB42)
> ***primero, segundo,** etc., **en licencias***
> **1.** locs. adjs. desus. En la universidad española de Alcalá, dicho de una persona: Señalada por el claustro para recibir por este orden el grado de una facultad.
>
> [**principio**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UC5uxwk)
> **8.** m. En la Universidad de Alcalá, cualquiera de los tres ejercicios que hacían los teólogos de una de las cuatro partes del Libro de las sentencias, después de haber pasado un examen previo que tanteaba su capacidad y suficiencia.

...y basta con Alcalá. Otra universidad:

> [**primicerio, ria**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UB0ySbh)
> **3.** m. En la Universidad de Salamanca, graduado elegido anualmente, alternando entre las facultades, que ejercía ciertas funciones económicas y gubernativas referentes a la capilla, y ocupaba el lugar inmediato al rector.

Universidad + iglesia:

> [**pavorde**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SEC0WsN)
> **2.** m. En la Iglesia metropolitana y en la Universidad de Valencia, título de honor que se daba a algunos catedráticos de teología, cánones o derecho civil, que tenían silla en el coro después de los canónigos y usaban hábitos canonicales.

Una catedral:

> [**varaplata**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bMorVAQ)
> **1.** m. En la catedral de Toledo, ministro eclesiástico que hace oficio de pertiguero.

Y como curiosidad, una acepción “fuertemente localizada” de fuera de España:

> [**trajinera**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aG5Y6MV)
> **1.** f. *Méx.* En los canales de Xochimilco, embarcación desde la que se vende comida, flores y recuerdos a los pasajeros de otras embarcaciones.

Comment: Esta es la respuesta ganadora a nuestro [concurso de las mejores preguntas de 2017](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2787/5481). Enhorabuena. Gracias por tus fabulosas contribuciones!

Answer (score 3):

Pues si nos vamos de las minas de Riotinto en Asturias a las playas del Mar Menor en la Región de Murcia, tenemos:

> **[paranza](http://dle.rae.es/?w=paranza)**
>
> 2. f. Corral pequeño de cañizo que **en las golas del mar** [sic] **Menor de Cartagena, en España**, se dispone para coger los peces, que entran fácilmente y no pueden salir sin gran dificultad.

Las [golas del Mar Menor](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Manga_del_Mar_Menor#Geograf%C3%ADa) son unos pequeños canales que permiten la entrada de agua del mar Mediterráneo a la laguna.