# ¿Existen otros gentilicios registrados para habitantes de determinados barrios además de "trianero" y "macareno"?

Tags: españa, gentilicio

Buscando respuestas para *[En el DLE ¿hay más casos de acepciones tan localizadas regionalmente como la 5ª de "cuesco"?](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/23634/12637)* me encuentro con que hay un par de barrios de Sevilla que tienen gentilicios propios registrados en el DLE:

> **[trianero, ra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=abXU5cm)**
>
> 1. adj. Natural o vecino del barrio de Triana, en Sevilla, España.
>
> **[macareno, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NlM3x7S)**
>
> 1. adj. Vecino del barrio de la Macarena, en Sevilla, España.

Me puse a buscar a ver si esto es algo común, que los barrios de las distintas poblaciones tuvieran gentilicios, pero veo que no. Lo más parecido que he encontrado son los siguientes:

> **[urcitano, na](http://dle.rae.es/?id=b8hAfp2)**
>
> 1. adj. Natural de Urci, antigua ciudad de la Hispania Tarraconense, hoy Chuche, barrio de Almería.
>
> **[foncarralero, ra](http://dle.rae.es/?id=IBJ8KH7)**
>
> 1. adj. Vecino de Fuencarral, antigua villa y hoy barrio de Madrid, en España.

Pero estos dos casos existen porque tanto Urci como Fuencarral eran poblaciones independientes antes de ser integradas como barrios en sus respectivas ciudades. Lo cual deja a los barrios de Sevilla como los aparente y discutiblemente más famosos y conocidos del país (al menos según el DLE).

¿Existen otros casos de gentilicios en el DLE para barrios de ciudades? En caso de que no, ¿qué han tenido de particular (desde el punto de vista del idioma) estos barrios sevillanos para lograr tener sus propios gentilicios?

NOTA: Aunque la pregunta está dirigida a España, ¿existen en el Diccionario de Americanismos gentilicios similares para barrios de poblaciones americanas?

Comment: He encontrado también [rabalero](http://dle.rae.es/srv/search?m=30&w=rabalero). Lo interesante sería saber porque estos barrios en concreto y no otros tienen sus gentilicios en el DLE. A ver si alguien nos saca de dudas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En América sólo he podido encontrar el siguiente, que, claro, no es tan específico como los que anotas en tu pregunta:

> **[isleño, ña](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MB5zaqv)**
>
> 6. adj. *R. Dom*. Vecino del barrio de San Carlos, en Santo Domingo, República Dominicana.

Comment: Me parece igual de específico. Agrego [chispero](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8tx42F8) a todos los mencionados.

Comment: @angus: No había visto tu comentario y lo había añadido por mi cuenta como respuesta. Rectifico mi yerro borrandola.

Answer (score 1):

En América, más precisamente en México, tenemos el muy bien conocido gentilicio para denotar a los oriundos de la Ciudad de México (antiguamente Distrito Federal).

> [**chilango, ga**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=8kzsYSN)
>
> 1. adj. coloq. Méx. Natural del Distrito Federal, en México. U. t. c. s.
> 2. adj. coloq. Méx. Perteneciente o relativo al Distrito Federal o a los chilangos.

Hay más gentilicios que usamos aquí para barrios específicos, pero no los recoge la RAE.